# HTML - After page load, page jumps down

Tags: html, firefox3.6

This problem has been bugging me for awhile. For some reason, after the page is finished or near-finished loading, the page jumps down, about half-way.

What I want to happen, and what I expect, is that pages remain at the top post-load.

Is there something I've done that could cause this?

For me it happens in Firefox 3.*

[Example 1](http://piggypeach.ecpod.com/2010/08/%E7%A9%BA%E7%93%B6%E8%B5%8F--2010%E5%B9%B48%E6%9C%88/)

[Example 2 - Empty Olay bottles](http://31df-blog.ecpod-dev.com/2009/12/why-chinglish-deserves-a-spot-in-the-hall-of-fusion-languages/)

Comment: Example 2 will not load for me. Example 1 displays at the top as expected.
[Edit]
Sorry, it did happen, but it was after the page finished "loading" in Firefox so I'm definitely thinking something Javascript coming into play.

Comment: Example 2 is broken. Edit: It takes some time after the page has loaded indeed.

Comment: @Airjoe fixed link. I thought so too, not sure what Script is causing it thought. @Kevin fixed. Yes the site is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On example 2, Ive had downloaded your site and the error appears to be in your common.js file, I think its the height function. (I removed it and it worked fine) maybe have a look into that?

Line 50-64

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it turns out that that whole class was redundant anyway, Prototype offers a way to get the viewport dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Some javascript code is causing this: when I turn off javascript the page stays at the top. Since there are like a gazillion lines of javascript code, I'm gonna leave the search of the code causing this to you. I would suggest to look for 'scrollTop' or something.

Comment: Thanks, deleted some unused library addition, seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This fault of page jumping down half a page might be due to Greasemonkey. By a process of elimination, found out which add-on was causing this jump. So disabled Greasemonkey to stop page jumping half way down, or use Greasemonkey and live with it. Both Greasemonkey and Firefox latest versions.
On my Firefox, autofocus did not fix page scroll part way down. Even after restart.